# VB.NET AlphaNumeric into integer

Tags: vb.net

If `Textbox1.text` contains a string value of `ZU4`, how can I convert that string to it's numeric ASCII codes, and output it to a second text box?

I'd like to do this using a `FOR LOOP` conditional statement which will read every character in INPUT?

Sample:

```
INPUT  Textbox1.Text = ZU4
OUTPUT Textbox2.Text = 908552
```

Comment: Well, first explain how you get from the input to the output. Do you mean `Z == 90`, `U == 85` etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the other answers will work with your given example, however, some of the suggestions are using unicode encoding rather than ASCII.  If strictly adhering to ASCII encoding is important, then you should explicitly specify the encoding that you want to use.

`Convert.ToInt32` uses UTF-16 encoding.  I'm not sure what `CInt` will do, but I suspect it works the same way.  Using `Asc` is better, but it is still dependent on the code page setting for the thread, so it's still not entirely safe.  Besides that, `Asc` is an old VB6 function which is provided in VB.NET, primarily for backwards compatibility.

Therefore, I would recommend using the `ASCIIEncoding` class instead.  You can get an instance of that class using the shared `ASCII` property of the `Encoding` class in the `System.Text` namespace, for instance:

```
Public Function ConvertTextToAsciiDigits(text As String) As String
    Dim builder As New StringBuilder()
    For Each b As Byte In Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text)
        builder.Append(b.ToString())
    Next
    Return builder.ToString()
End Function
```

Then, you can call the function like this:

```
Textbox2.Text = ConvertTextToAsciiDigits(Textbox1.Text)
```

However, I can't imagine that the resulting string will be usable unless every character results in a two digit number.  Therefore, I would force it to be two digits by doing something like this:

```
Public Function ConvertTextToAsciiDigits(text As String) As String
    Dim builder As New StringBuilder()
    For Each b As Byte In Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text)
        If b > 99 then
            Throw New FormatException()  ' Throws an exception if the value is three digits
        End If
        builder.Append(b.ToString("00"))  ' Adds a leading zero to one-digit values
    Next
    Return builder.ToString()
End Function
```

To add a hyphen after every fourth digit, as you mentioned in a comment below, you could just keep track of the total digits added since the last hyphen, like this:

```
Public Function ConvertTextToAsciiDigits(text As String) As String
    Dim builder As New StringBuilder()
    Dim digitsSinceHyphen As Integer = 0
    For Each b As Byte In Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text)
        If b > 99 then
            Throw New FormatException()
        End If
        builder.Append(b.ToString("00"))
        digitsSinceHyphen += 2
        If digitsSinceHyphen >= 4 Then
            builder.Append("-")
            digitsSinceHyphen = 0
        End If
    Next
    Return builder.ToString()
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Steven..how about appending a hypen "-" in every four (4) character in Textbox2.Text?

Comment: So you want a hyphen after every set of four digits?  Like after every two byte values?  Like "9085-52"?

Comment: Oops.  A couple little bugs.  I fixed the examples in my answers.  They should work properly now.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use LINQ:

```
TextBox2.Text = String.Join(String.Empty, From c In Textbox1.Text.ToCharArray Select (Asc(c).ToString))
```

Could be useful on some job interviews... :)

Comment: i have no knowledge in LINQ but i will try to figure it out soon and learn LINQ in your shortest one line of code..this one save kilobytes of codes..thank you Grzegorz

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach, in C#:

```
Textbox2.Text = string.Empty;
foreach(var c in Textbox1.Text)
{
  Textbox2.Text += ((int)c).ToString();
}
```

VB.NET:

```
Textbox2.Text = String.Empty
For Each c As Char In Textbox1.Text
  Textbox2.Text = Textbox2.Text + Convert.ToInt32(c).ToString()
Next
```

It:

- Clears out `Textbox2.Text`
- Loops over each character in the input
- Concatenates the integer value output as a string to the output text

Comment: and also this one is the same thing..with direct and simple codes and with explanation line by line..thank you Oded..this one is good for beginners using Convert.ToInt32()

Answer (score 0):

```
TextBox2.Text = ""
For i As Integer = 0 To TextBox1.TextLength - 1
    TextBox2.Text += Asc(TextBox1.Text(i)).ToString()
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

i modified the code from this [Link](http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/19462)

```
Function AsciiEncode(ByVal value As String) As String
            Dim encValue As New System.Text.StringBuilder(value.Length * 6)
            Dim c As Char
            For Each c In value
                encValue.Append(Convert.ToInt32(c))
            Next
            Return encValue.ToString()
End Function
```

**usage:**

```
   Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        TextBox2.Text = AsciiEncode(TextBox1.Text)
    End Sub
```

Comment: also this one is the same thing as previously posted although this automatically changed the value in TextBox2.Text quicky..superb answer..this answer my queries quicky..thank you so much..